# What are the various ways to host a Blackberry APP

Tags: blackberry, hosting

I have developed a blackberry app, now i am confused on How to host, there are different answers available for this on Web

Some says it is ok to host it on a 3rd party server and some says I need to get a vendor portal account,

Please suggest what is the best way and what is the procedure to host a bb app?

Comment: Is this a BlackBerry Java app?

Comment: Yes It is developed using Java

Answer (score 1):

There is an extensive paper on all deployment methods available from RIM:
[A70  – How to Deploy and Distribute Applications For BlackBerry SmartPhones](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/117/1/How_to_Deploy_and_Distribute_Applications_V1.pdf)

Comment: Hi Thanks, I am trying on the air solution and hosted my app on my own server and have also added required settings in .htaccess to allow download of file, but after successfull download I am getting "907 invalid cod" error, but when i install application through bb messenger through it's alx file, it is working fine, can you please address this situation?

Comment: Not enough information here to be of much help. Are you sure you have all the COD files hosted on the server? If your application is large there could be seveal COD files.

Comment: Yes I have uploaded the entire OTA folder